# JS WebDriverIO how to check if tag h1 is present on a page

Tags: javascript, io

I tried doing like this:

```
await browser.url(https://webdriver.io/');
expect(browser).toHaveText('h1')
```

so tried:

```
await browser.url(https://webdriver.io/');
await browser.findElement('xpath', 'h1')
```

But it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i solved the issue:

```
const url = 'https://webdriver.io/';
const crossFetch = require('cross-fetch');
const links = [];

describe('test', async () => {
    beforeEach(async function () {
        const result = await crossFetch(`${url}/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?per_page=100`);
        const pages = await result.json();
        pages.forEach(page => links.push(page.link));
    });

    it('Check Headers', async () => {
        const errorsUrls = [];

        for (const url of links) {
            await browser.url(url);
            const classNameAndText = await $('h3');

            if (typeof classNameAndText.error !== 'undefined') {
                errorsUrls.push(url);
            }
        }

        if (errorsUrls.length > 0) {
            throw new Error( `
                Header Not Found:
                ${errorsUrls.join('\r\n')}
            `);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can someone tell me how to check for the presence of the h1 tag in the loop? The test immediately crashes and does not print pages that do not have h1

```
const url = 'https://webdriver.io/';
const crossFetch = require('cross-fetch');
const links = [];

describe('test', async () => {
    beforeEach(async function () {
        const result = await crossFetch(`${url}/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?per_page=100`);
        const pages = await result.json();
        pages.forEach(page => links.push(page.link));
    });

    it('Check Headers', async () => {
        const array1 = [];
        const array2 = [];

        for (const elem of links) {
            await browser.url(elem);
            elem.click;

            const classNameAndText = await $('<h1>')
            console.log('HAS h1 - ' + await classNameAndText.getText()) // outputs: h1

            if (classNameAndText) {
                array1.push(elem);
            } else {
                array2.push(elem);
            }
        }
        if (array2.length > 0) {
            array2.forEach(function (elem1) {
                console.log('NOT h1 - ' + elem1);
            })
        }
    })
});
```